# Copying DataRow into new DataTable, with appropriate types from original DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, datarow, datacolumn

Consider a `DataTable`, of which a subset is to be copied into a new `DataTable`. The subset is a certain number of rows, up to a certain index. Currently, it is being done with the following code:

```
DataTable toDisplay = new DataTable();
// dataSource is the original DataTable
foreach (DataColumn col in dataSource.Columns)
    toDisplay.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(col.ColumnName, col.GetType()));

for (int i = 0; i < maxIndex; i++)
{
    var index = i;
    var currentRow = dataSoure.Rows[index];

    object[] currentRowItems = currentRow.ItemArray; // this is the problematic line
    toDisplay.Rows.Add(currentRowItems);
}
```

The problem with this approach is that the rows in the resulting table don't have the specific types from the original table. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Clone`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.clone):

> Clones the structure of the DataTable, including all DataTable schemas
> and constraints.

Therefore you can simply do that as follows:

```
DataTable toDisplay = dataSource.Clone();

for (int i = 0; i < maxIndex; i++)
{
    var index = i;
    var currentRow = dataSource.Rows[index];
    
    toDisplay.ImportRow(currentRow);
}
```

Comment: This throws an exception: `System.ArgumentException: 'This row already belongs to another table.'`